# Improving design skills

Tags: website-design, design-principles

I've been practicing front-end web design for almost 4 months now (and by that I mean design, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript). I've found that I excel in terms of writing code and markup, but my design skills aren't really up to par.

How would you suggest I get an eye for designing nice interfaces? Have any of you ever been in a position like mine (with no art/design experience) and managed to become a great designer?

Comment: ...and since you mention having no art/design background, if/when you start applying for design jobs, see [What are some tips for getting hired without a formal design education?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/what-are-some-tips-for-getting-hired-without-a-formal-education) - hope that all helps!

Comment: See also - [Tips and sources for beginning designers](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-sources-for-beginning-designers/), plus [How do I learn to be creative?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/how-do-i-learn-to-be-creative), and, when you start making progress, [How would I know how good of a designer I am?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13808/how-would-i-know-how-good-of-a-designer-i-am)